# Render Velocity inside {{html}} in XWiki to generate page links

Tags: html, velocity, xwiki

I'm running XWiki and developing a page. I have a Velocity script and inside it {{html}} and in the html I'm using a bootstrap panel. I want a list of links to appear in the panel. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
{{velocity}}
{{html}}
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-body">
             <p> ... Display links from macro... </p>
         </div>
    </div>
{{/html}}
{{/velocity}}
```

The macro gives me the links I want:

```
#getChildrenOf("Classes.WebHome")

#macro(getChildrenOf, $docName)
    #foreach($name in $xwiki.searchDocuments('where doc.parent = ? or doc.parent = ? order by doc.name', [$docName, "xwiki:$docName"]))
         #if($xwiki.hasAccessLevel('view', "xwiki:$name"))
             [[$xwiki.getDocument($name).getPlainTitle()>>$name]]
         #else
             $xwiki.getDocument($name).getPlainTitle()
         #end
         #getChildrenOf($name)
    #end
#end
```

The output is:

[[COMPLETE>>Classes.COMPLETE]] [[DOMAIN>>Classes.DOMAIN]] [[LEVEL>>Classes.LEVEL]]

Rendered as HTML text. How can I render this as velocity in the HTML? If I close the HTML acround the velocity it breaks the HTML panel as the HTML tags do not close. Can I somehow sale the list in a variable and display it in the panel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have Wiki Syntax interpreted inside a `{{html}}`-macro, you need to use the `wiki="true"` parameter, like:

```
{{velocity}}
{{html wiki="true"}}
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-body">
             <p> Link to home page: [[WebHome]] </p>
         </div>
    </div>
{{/html}}
{{/velocity}}
```

If you omit this paramater it defaults to `wiki="false"` - i.e. Wiki-Syntax is not interpreted inside the macro.

For Reference of the `{{html}}`-macro see and its parameters: http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/HTML+Macro

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing the [[s with tags and calling the velocity functions solved the problem.

```
<a href="$xwiki.getURL($name)">$xwiki.getDocument($name).getPlainTitle()</a><br>
```